# NodeJS request object is empty on GET request

Tags: html, node.js, request, get-request

I have a code where i am trying to get some value from a drop down menu using a get request. However, when i click on submit, the request object is empty. i did use the body parser and `bodyParser.json` and declared them before the routes, however the request object is still empty:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var EventHubClient = require('azure-event-hubs').Client;

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
console.log('');
};


app.get('/result', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/result.html');
});

app.get('/index', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/getJson', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

here is the index.html file:

```
<form id="tableForm" action="/getJson" method="get">
    <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info" name="selectpicker">
        <optgroup label="Select Table">
            <option name="" value="0">Select table</option>
            <option name="table1" value="1">Table 1</option>
            <option name="table2" value="2">Table 2</option>
            <option name="table3" value="3">Table 3</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to change the form method to **`POST`** in your *index.html* page:

```
<form id="tableForm" action="/getJson" method="get">
                                               ^^^
```

Now, since the method is **`POST`** in your HTML page, you have to make changes in this code snippet too:

```
app.get('/getJson', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

The changes will be reflected as:

```
app.post('/getJson', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end();    //You must add this line as well.
});
```

[image: response]

Comment: Thankyou. This manages to solve the issue. Can you explain why did you use POST instead of get for form?

Comment: You must read the [basics](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) first :)

Comment: On the other note, how can i redirect from the /getJson to another page, for example result.html?

Answer (score 0):

Try post method in your form in index.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use `POST` method to pass data.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var EventHubClient = require('azure-event-hubs').Client;

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
console.log('');
};


app.get('/result', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/result.html');
});

app.get('/index', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/getJson', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

index.html

```
<form id="tableForm" action="/getJson" method="post">
    <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info" name="selectpicker">
        <optgroup label="Select Table">
            <option name="" value="0">Select table</option>
            <option name="table1" value="1">Table 1</option>
            <option name="table2" value="2">Table 2</option>
            <option name="table3" value="3">Table 3</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```